# How to efficiently find if path exists between vertices in a directed graph after deleting one vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graph

Before removing a vertex from a directed cyclic graph, I want to check if all its adjacent vertices will remain connected to one specific sink vertex (which never changes) after removal (and if they are not, the vertex will not be removed). The algorithm should be online (but I do not mind storing auxiliary data), and the graph can only change at any time through additions of vertices (and edges at the same time) or through this removal process.

I've tried doing a DFS and a BFS from the sink vertex but they are too slow, so I am looking for something faster than O(n). I've also tried using a priority queue with the heuristic being the distance to the vertex-to-be-removed, but it's not very helpful because the worst case of the removal being invalid occurs often.

Comment: For the record, for undirected graphs this is known as [biconnectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). The vertices whose removal would split the graph into two components are known as articulation points. The online variant of this problem is discussed in [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/research/techreps/TR-228-89) paper.